Confusing notation in a partial derivative from a textbook called "A first course in calculus of variations"
While trying to understand functional derivatives (also known as variations) I came across this partial derivative in a book called "A first course in calculus of variations" by Mark Kot:

What I don't understand about the partial derivative shown in (2.7) is why the first term has $f_y$ and the other two have $f_{y'}$. I tried re-reading the previous chapter (this is from chapter 2) but couldn't find anything about this notation.
Trying to derive it myself resulted in an identical expression except that I had $f_{y_k}$ instead of $f_{y}$ and $f_{y'}$ (which raises another question as to why the text has $f_y$ and not $f_{y_k}$).
I thought the  derivative is straightforward; $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} f(g(y_k)) = f_{y_k}(g(y_k)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}g(y_k)$.
Here is my attempt:

I tried looking up other texts that show this derivation but couldn't find anything that is sufficiently similar for a comparison. What am I missing? I don't think it is a typo in the book because the pages that follow are consistent with this result and notation.

I assume that the function $f$ is originally given as a function of $x$, $y$, and $y' = dy/dx$, i.e. $f(x,y,y')$? If so, then the notation $f_{y'}$ just means a derivative of $f$ with respect to its third argument.

@JohnBarber It is. But if that is the case then I don't understand why would the expression for $\frac{\partial J}{\partial y_k}$ have $f_{y'}$ in it. Where does it come from? What am I doing wrong in my derivation?

The notation $f_x,f_y,f_{y'}$ is very common and frequently used in physics also. It means nothing else than $\partial_1f,\partial_2f,\partial_3f$ where the indices label the three arguments of $f,.$ Formula (2.7) correctly reflects the fact that a fixed $y_k$ enters into $J$ in three different ways. Hence it is a consequence of the chain rule.

It seems everyone only reads my question until the middle so I'll just repost it without the notation part...

Don't repost it. Waste of time. Highlight or mention again what is still unclear.

@KurtG. I bolded the part of the question that is still unclear to me. I don't see where $f_{y'}$ comes from.

See my answer and I herewith bold again that $f_{y'}$ is nothing else than $\partial_3f,.$

@KurtG. I understand the notation now. What I don't understand is why is there a derivative w.r.t y' in the first place. Furthermore, why are they with respect to y and y' and not y_k?

That is no derivative w.r.t. $y'$! Hence we call it detestable notation. It is the partial derivative of $f(u,v,w)$ with respect to its third argument.

@KurtG. Call it w.r.t to y' or w.r.t to the 3rd argument - I still don't see why the three terms of f there don't have the same subscript

If my answer below where I highlighted $\color{red}{y_k}$ in the two relevant slots of $f$ does not answer that question I can only quit now. Running out of ideas.

@kurtG. Oh I think I see it now. I've misused the chain rule. Now I understand your highlighting.


Fix $k\,.$ By definition of $J(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ the $y_k$ with this $k$ enters into the terms
$$\tag1
f\left(x_k,\color{red}{y_k},\frac{y_{k+1}-\color{red}{y_k}}{\Delta x}\right)\Delta x
$$
and
$$
f\left(x_{k-1},y_{k-1},\frac{\color{red}{y_k}-y_{k-1}}{\Delta x}\right)\Delta x\,.
$$

Now write $\partial_1f\,,\partial_2f\,,\partial_3f$ instead of the detestable $f_x,f_y,f_{y'}$ and use the chain rule. This leads immediately to (2.7):

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_k}$ applied to (1) gives



$$\require{cancel}\partial_2f\left(x_k,\color{red}{y_k},\frac{y_{k+1}-\color{red}{y_k}}{\Delta x}\right)\Delta x-\cancel{\frac1{\Delta x}}\partial_3f\left(x_k,\color{red}{y_k},\frac{y_{k+1}-\color{red}{y_k}}{\Delta x}\right)\cancel{\Delta x}\,.$$


$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_k}$ applied to (2) gives


$$\require{cancel}\cancel{\frac1{\Delta x}}\partial_3f\left(x_{k-1},y_{k-1},\frac{\color{red}{y_k}-y_{k-1}}{\Delta x}\right)\cancel{\Delta x}\,.$$

